# Problem when creating database based on template_postgis

Tags: postgis, topology

I have created a PostGIS template but when I try to create a database based on this template this is what happens:

Connecting to the template:

```
\c template_postgis;

You are now connected to database "template_postgis" as user "postgres".

\dt
               List of relations
  Schema  |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   
----------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public   | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
 topology | layer           | table | postgres
 topology | topology        | table | postgres
(3 rows)

create database prueba with TEMPLATE template_postgis;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Connecting to database prueba:

```
\c prueba;
You are now connected to database "prueba" as user "postgres".

prueba=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

You can see only the public schema was copied, no topology schema layer or topology were copied.

I had no errors when I created the template:

```
#createdb template_postgis
      #createlang plpgsql template_postgis
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql 
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis_comments.sql 
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql 
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/rtpostgis.sql
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/raster_comments.sql 
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/topology.sql 
      #psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/topology_comments.sql
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search_path in the new database probably does not include the 'topology' schema, try adding it.

Comment: Paul, Thanks for your answer. It's true that topology it's not in my search_path.